# Storing data about undirected graph edges in a database

Tags: sql, hash, graph

I have a data structure that is an undirected graph (probably dense) with nodes and edges. The edge between nodes I and J will have additional data associated with it and I want to be able to uniquely identify that edge when querying *and to be able to quickly determine if an edge between I and J exists*.

I have decided to accomplish this using two tables:

```
Table Nodes
-----------
node_id PK
...
(additional fields)


Table Edges
-----------
nodes_hash(node_id, node_id) PK
edge_thickness
...
(additional fields)
```

where the primary key for every edge will be computed by a hash function `nodes_hash(node_id, node_id)` taking two node IDs.

My questions:

- How do I come up with a good hash function to compute edge IDs?
- Any major drawbacks to this approach that I may be overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason why you should need to encode edges as hashes: ensuring that there are no duplicates is a simple matter of a unique constraint.

While there are ways of calculating hashes (creating a path enumeration string, and calculating its MD5 hash or something along those lines), there's no value in storing the hash and not use a path enumeration scheme for storing the graph data itself. Path enumeration works exactly like it does in the filesystem, storing something like `/a/b/c` (if enumerating by node id) or `1.2.1.5` (if enumerating by edge ordinal).

For your specific usecase I would use a common adjacency list table setup (unless other operations in the tree call for more specialized data structures such as node sets or path/edge enumeration). In this structure, the top-level node has `PARENT_ID = NULL`:

```
CREATE TABLE NODES(
  NODE_ID INT NOT NULL,
  -- OTHER NODE ATTRIBUTES
  PRIMARY KEY (NODE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE EDGES(
  NODE_ID INT NOT NULL,
  PARENT_ID INT,
  EDGE_WEIGHT INT NOT NULL,
  -- OTHER EDGE ATTRIBUTES
  FOREIGN KEY (NODE_ID) REFERENCES NODES(NODE_ID), 
  FOREIGN KEY (PARENT_ID) REFERENCES NODES(NODE_ID),
  CHECK (PARENT_ID <> NODE_ID),                   -- This avoids simple cycles
  CONSTRAINT UNIQ_EDGE UNIQUE (NODE_ID,PARENT_ID) -- This avoids duplicate edges
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would use use a hash function to generate such a key?

I would have an integer primary key (node id) for the nodes.

I would have an integer primary key (edge id) for the edges.

Then I would have two columns in the edge table for each node, with foreign key relationships to back to the node table.

I can readily think of two drawbacks to using a hash function.  First, you can have collisions.  In fact, if everything is stored as integers, then you *will* have collisions just by the pigeon hole principle.

Second, you need to store the node ids anyway.  Almost any graph problem that I can think of needs to know the nodes connected by edges.

You would handle an undirected graph is the following constraints/triggers:

(1) Add a contraint/trigger that node1 < node 2 (or <= if self-connection is allowed).

(2) Add a unique index on node1, node2.

(3) Add a before-insert trigger to be sure that for arbitrary values, node1 gets the lesser value and node2 gets the larger value.

In Oracle, you can combine these by having a function-based index on least(node1, node2) and the greatest(node1, node).

Comment: The reason I want to use a hash function is to avoid duplicate entries in the Edges table: I want a unique entry for the edge between I and J. The solution you describe would allow the creation of two records for the edge between I and J. I want to avoid the complexity of doing the various checks in the SQL queries when looking for the edge between two nodes in the table.

Comment: can't you use the pair of node ids as a composite key of your edge table ? or do you need to support multigraphs ? the proposed scheme supports undirected graphs if you compose node ids in a defined order.